# What's the significance of CONFIG_CGROUPS in Kernel 4.12?

Tags: linux-kernel, embedded-linux

I have an embedded system with power pc architecture 87xx. If I don't enable the "CONFIG_CGROUPS" in Linux kernel I can't mount the devtmpf i.e. ubifs file system.I am trying to understand what't the dependency of CGROUPS in mounting the nand filesystem running UBIFS.If I enable the CGROUPS then I can't execute the /sbin/init of the mounted root file system. What I could be doing wrong here?

This happens if I **don't** turned the CONFIG_CGROUPS=y in kernel.

```
    Zone ranges:
  DMA      [mem 0x0000000000000000-0x000000001fffffff]
  Normal   empty
Movable zone start for each node
Early memory node ranges
  node   0: [mem 0x0000000000000000-0x000000001fffffff]
Initmem setup node 0 [mem 0x0000000000000000-0x000000001fffffff]
Built 1 zonelists in Zone order, mobility grouping on.  Total pages: 130048
Kernel command line: ubi.mtd=1 rootfstype=ubifs root=ubi0:discofs rw console=tty                                                                                                                                                             S1,115200 serno=91101316 sku=700064090C hwrev==00:90:5E:12:32:05 mac1=00:90:5E:1                                                                                                                                                             2:32:06 mac2=00:90:5E:12:32:07 mac3=00:90:5E:12:32:08 mac4=00:90:5E:12:32:09
PID hash table entries: 2048 (order: 1, 8192 bytes)
Dentry cache hash table entries: 65536 (order: 6, 262144 bytes)
Inode-cache hash table entries: 32768 (order: 5, 131072 bytes)
Memory: 511944K/524288K available (5972K kernel code, 272K rwdata, 1192K rodata,                                                                                                                                                              192K init, 128K bss, 12344K reserved, 0K cma-reserved)
Kernel virtual memory layout:
  * 0xfffdf000..0xfffff000  : fixmap
  * 0xfdffe000..0xfe000000  : early ioremap
  * 0xe1000000..0xfdffe000  : vmalloc & ioremap
NR_IRQS:512 nr_irqs:512 16
IPIC (128 IRQ sources) at e1000700
clocksource: timebase: mask: 0xffffffffffffffff max_cycles: 0x12049cd416, max_id                                                                                                                                                             le_ns: 440795202745 ns
clocksource: timebase mult[ccccccd] shift[24] registered
pid_max: default: 32768 minimum: 301
Mount-cache hash table entries: 1024 (order: 0, 4096 bytes)
Mountpoint-cache hash table entries: 1024 (order: 0, 4096 bytes)
devtmpfs: initialized
clocksource: jiffies: mask: 0xffffffff max_cycles: 0xffffffff, max_idle_ns: 7645                                                                                                                                                             041785100000 ns
futex hash table entries: 256 (order: -1, 3072 bytes)
NET: Registered protocol family 16

PCI: Probing PCI hardware
Freescale Elo series DMA driver
vgaarb: loaded
SCSI subsystem initialized
pps_core: LinuxPPS API ver. 1 registered
pps_core: Software ver. 5.3.6 - Copyright 2005-2007 Rodolfo Giometti <giometti@l                                                                                                                                                             inux.it>
PTP clock support registered
clocksource: Switched to clocksource timebase
NET: Registered protocol family 2
TCP established hash table entries: 4096 (order: 2, 16384 bytes)
TCP bind hash table entries: 4096 (order: 2, 16384 bytes)
TCP: Hash tables configured (established 4096 bind 4096)
UDP hash table entries: 256 (order: 0, 4096 bytes)
UDP-Lite hash table entries: 256 (order: 0, 4096 bytes)
NET: Registered protocol family 1
RPC: Registered named UNIX socket transport module.
RPC: Registered udp transport module.
RPC: Registered tcp transport module.
RPC: Registered tcp NFSv4.1 backchannel transport module.
fsl-elo-dma e00082a8.dma: #0 (fsl,elo-dma-channel), irq 71
fsl-elo-dma e00082a8.dma: #1 (fsl,elo-dma-channel), irq 71
fsl-elo-dma e00082a8.dma: #2 (fsl,elo-dma-channel), irq 71
fsl-elo-dma e00082a8.dma: #3 (fsl,elo-dma-channel), irq 71
workingset: timestamp_bits=30 max_order=17 bucket_order=0
NFS: Registering the id_resolver key type
Key type id_resolver registered
Key type id_legacy registered
jffs2: version 2.2. (NAND) © 2001-2006 Red Hat, Inc.
SGI XFS with security attributes, no debug enabled
io scheduler noop registered
io scheduler deadline registered
io scheduler cfq registered (default)
Serial: 8250/16550 driver, 4 ports, IRQ sharing disabled
Oops: Exception in kernel mode, sig: 4 [#1]
disco
Modules linked in:
CPU: 0 PID: 8 Comm: kdevtmpfs Not tainted 4.12.28-disco-standard #1
task: df41b580 task.stack: df438000
NIP: c0100000 LR: c00fb708 CTR: c00b462c
REGS: df439c50 TRAP: 0700   Not tainted  (4.12.28-disco-standard)
MSR: 00089032 <EE,ME,IR,DR,RI>
  CR: 880ad872  XER: 00000000

GPR00: c00fb708 df439d00 df41b580 df69c170 00000000 df69c170 00000002 00000000
GPR08: 00000000 00000007 00000001 0e4e1c2f 280ad872 00000000 c0040514 df41d120
GPR16: 00000000 014000c0 00000007 00000000 00000000 0000002f 00000000 c078c840
GPR24: fffff000 00000000 00000000 df69c1cc df69c170 df41fd18 00000000 df69c170
NIP [c0100000] iput+0x24/0x1c8
LR [c00fb708] d_delete+0xb8/0xfc
Call Trace:
[df439d00] [c00fb000] dentry_unlink_inode+0xf0/0x164 (unreliable)
[df439d20] [c00fb708] d_delete+0xb8/0xfc
[df439d40] [c00eecc4] vfs_unlink+0x1b8/0x210
[df439d70] [c03c4f2c] handle_remove+0x1b0/0x324
[df439e50] [c03c5200] devtmpfsd+0x160/0x34c
[df439f00] [c0040650] kthread+0x13c/0x140
[df439f40] [c00103f0] ret_from_kernel_thread+0x5c/0x64
Instruction dump:
39200001 7d234b78 4e800020 9421ffe0 93e1001c 7c7f1b79 41820094 7c0802a6
93a10014 90010024 93c10018 813f0058 <27051956> 9188a4bd 5d2e9c29 0039c48b
---[ end trace df78166105247941 ]---
```

Comment: That's not a meaningful excerpt of the console output.  You need to show the entire panic or OOPS or whatever happens.  And providing context (i.e. preceding lines before the event) can help to indicate when it occurs.

Comment: I have added the entire boot log now. I am unable to understand the root cause here? Why CG Group matters when mounting the rootfs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is you have a systemd-based system. In which case, init is provided by systemd, so is population of /dev. Systemd, in turn, makes extensive use of CGROUPS.

The ubifs/devtmpfs link is not a direct one, IMO. ubifs could be used without it too as long as /dev is correctly populated.